# Angular evaluation of expression in html tag

Tags: angularjs

in my controller I create an associative array with values pointing to true/false values for example:

```
$scope.mylist["val1"]=true;
$scope.mylist["val2"]=false;
```

and I want to create checkboxes that are ticked or not accordingly to the values of each items in my list. The css framework I use requires to add the checked="checked" to make the checkbox checked. And this is where the problem beggins. I tried checked={{value ? "checked" : ""}} but it doesn't work. SO which is the right way to do it?

```
    <div class="" ng-repeat="(key,value) in mylist">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{key}}" ng-click="toggleSelectUnit(key)" checked="checked" ng-if="value">
                <input type="checkbox" id="{{key}}" ng-click="toggleSelectUnit(key)"  ng-if="!value">
                <label for="{{key}}">{{key}}</label>

</div>
```

For now I came up with this workaround which is stupid. Is there any better and more elegant way to do it?

Thx in advance

Comment: You should just use ng-model to bind the checkbox to the boolean attribute. Your CSS stylesheet should use something like `input:checked { ... }` to style checked inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ng-checked.

```
<input
  ng-checked="expression">
...
</input>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked